# how to record mic input and pipe the output to another program

Tags: audio-recording, sox, random-number-generator

Hi everyone Im trying to follow a tutorial on generating truly random bits

[How To Generate Truly Random Bits](http://openfortress.org/cryptodoc/random/)

This is the command from the tutorial but it does not work

```
rec -c 1 -d /dev/dsp -r 8000 -t wav -s w  - | ./noise-filter >bits
```

I know i can record my mic input using

```
rec -c 1 no.wav
```

this is the command i tried using

```
rec -c 1 -r 8000 -t wav -s noise.wav | ./noise-filter >bits
```

but i get

```
root@xxc:~/cc# rec -c 1 -r 8000 -t wav -s noise.wav  - | ./noise-filter >bits
rec WARN formats: can't set sample rate 8000; using 48000
rec FAIL sox: Input files must have the same sample-rate
```

I have complied noise-filter

[noise-filter](http://openfortress.org/cryptodoc/random/noise-filter.c)

I think the tutorial is using an older version of SOX and REC I'm using

```
sox: SoX v14.3.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 server
```

Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 4):

This command line has too many outputs listed:

```
rec -c 1 -r 8000 -t wav -s noise.wav - | ./noise-filter >bits
                           ^file     ^standard output
```

For a command pipeline, the only output should be the `-` at the end. The `rec` command interprets the `noise.wav` parameter as an additional input, which will fail or produce bogus output. Try removing the extra filename (and other unnecessary/incompatible options):

```
rec -c 1 -t wav - | ./noise-filter > bits
```

Answer (score 2):

per the tutorial you referenced (I'm following that one, too!) AND the latest-version SoX manpage (as of 9 Nov 2014), the complete, corrected command that worked for me was:

`rec -c 1 -r 8000 -t raw -e signed-integer -2  - | ./noise-filter > bits`

ent returned these values for a 49,152-byte file:

```
Entropy = 7.996356 bits per byte.

Optimum compression would reduce the size
of this 49152 byte file by 0 percent.

Chi square distribution for 49152 samples is 247.53, and randomly
would exceed this value 50.00 percent of the times.

Arithmetic mean value of data bytes is 127.5771 (127.5 = random).
Monte Carlo value for Pi is 3.147949219 (error 0.20 percent).
Serial correlation coefficient is -0.002336 (totally uncorrelated = 0.0).
```

This is pretty good quality random data!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your noise.wav is not at a sample rate that sox can record in, and sox requires both files to be at the same sample rate. You'll probably have to regenerate noise.wav at a higher sample rate.